# running 2 SSL listeners on ELB with different ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-elb

I have a springboot web application that is running in an AWS EC2. The application is running behind a classic ELB. I am using HTTPS between the client and the ELB so traffic coming in on port 443 is being routed to port 8080 I have deployed the certificate to the ELB.

In the same application I have an embedded ActiveMQ running on port 61616. It is running as part of the JVM. Clients connect to it using TCP (TCP://domain.com:61616).
I want the client to connect to my AMQ using SSL similar to the way they connect to the application (through HTTPS).
I have added a listener to the ELB where the client connects to the ELB using SSL (SSL://domain.com:61616) and the ELB routes to the internal port using TCP and I have deployed the same certificate to the ELB as the one I used for the application. for example here is what I have:
[image]
Basically I want to use SSL between the client and the ELB and TCP from ELB to the instance.
Why this doesn't work? when I try to connect using openssl

openssl s_client -connect domain.com:61616

I get the following:

`CONNECTED(00000003)

### write:errno=104

### no peer certificate available

### No client certificate CA names sent

### SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 247 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---`
Why I cannot use a different port other than 443 to use SSL?